# How to detect hover state on touchscreen device - Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, hover, touch, vuejs3, touch-event

In my case in desktop mode user can hover over the element to reveal the menu. User can also click the element that makes a request to the server.

In touchscreen mode, I would like the click to be revealing the menu instead of making a request.

It seems like impossible task to achieve unless I start going outside of vue and changing css directly from DOM level.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const text = ref("whatever");
const isEditing = ref(false);
function sendToServer() {
  console.log("Sending request of ", text.value, " to server.")
  isEditing.value = false;
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span v-show="!isEditing" @click="sendToServer" @touchstart.prevent> {{ text }}</span>
    <input v-show="isEditing" v-model="text">
    <span @click="sendToServer" class="icon">➡️</span>
    <span @click="isEditing = !isEditing" class="icon">✏️</span>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .icon {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .wrapper:hover .icon {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .wrapper > span {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

[Vue SFC playground link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: What about long press for mobile / touch-device users? You can achieve this with a directive, something [like this](https://github.com/Lissy93/dashy/blob/FEATURE/sub-items/src/directives/LongPress.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"It seems like impossible task to achieve unless I start going outside of vue and changing css directly from DOM level."*

I would say it is impossible to achieve with CSS-only, but Vue (IMHO) seems cable and well suited to handle that.

Instead of using css `:hover` you will need to manage the visibility using state (`isSelected` in example)

then use `@touchstart` to toggle visibility - this will only be available to touch devices and mouse events `@mouseover` to show and `@mouseout` to hide.

there may be some more finessing to handle some edge cases, but this is how I'd implement it. For example, you may need a global touch event listener to hide when user clicks outside of the text.

```html
<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";

  const text = ref("whatever");
  const isEditing = ref(false);
  const isSelected = ref(false);
  function toggleIsSelected(){
        isSelected.value = !isSelected.value
  }
  function unselect(){
    isSelected.value = false;
  }
  function sendToServer() {
    console.log("Sending request of ", text.value, " to server.")
    isEditing.value = false;
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span v-show="!isEditing"
          @click="sendToServer"
          @touchstart=toggleIsSelected
          @mouseover=toggleIsSelected
          @mouseout=unselect
    > {{ text }}</span>
    <input v-show="isEditing" v-model="text">
    <span v-show=isSelected @click="sendToServer" class="icon">➡️</span>
    <span v-show=isSelected @click="isEditing = !isEditing" class="icon">✏️</span>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .wrapper > span {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```